# List elements collection

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections, lambda

I got a list:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("x1");
list.Add("x2");
list.Add("x3");
list.Add("x4");
.
.
.
.
list.Add("x100");
```

Now I need a collection of List, containing exactly 10 elements from listofX.

So that List1 has 1 to 10 elements from listofX , list2 has 11 to 20 elements from listofX.

Can this be done with Lambda expression or LINQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
var lists = Enumerable
    .Range(0,10)
    .Select(x=>
        Enumerable
            .Range(x*10+1,10)
            .Select(y=>"x" + y.ToString()));
```

If you are looking for a generic approach, then perhaps...

```
 var list=Enumerable.Range(1,100).Select(y=>"x" + y.ToString());
 var newlist=Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(x=>list.Skip(x*10).Take(10));
```

Or finally, you can use a extension method like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<List<T>> InSetsOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int max)
    {
        var toReturn = new List<T>(max);
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            toReturn.Add(item);
            if (toReturn.Count == max)
            {
                yield return toReturn;
                toReturn = new List<T>(max);
            }
        }
        if (toReturn.Any())
        {
            yield return toReturn;
        }
    }
```

and you can use it like this:

```
var newList=list.InSetsOf(10);
```

Comment: The second range should be a combination of skip and take though, as the "x1" is probably a placeholder.

Comment: If it's a placeholder, then yes.  It would need to be reworked, and I would likely use a different approach.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done like:

```
var list1 = list.Take(10).ToList();
var list2 = list.Skip(10).Take(10).ToList();
var list3 = list.Skip(20).Take(10).ToList();
```

and so on

Or more generally:

```
var number = list.Count / 10;
var lists = new List<List<string>>(number);

for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    lists.Add(list.Skip(i * 10).Take(10));
```

This will create list of those lists.

Comment: Very elegent and simple. Nice one

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a way to batch a list, it is fairly straight forward to write an IEnumerable extension to achieve that.

Here is the code that you can use as is:

```
public static class Extensions      {
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> BreakIntoChunks<TSource >(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int size)
            {
                TSource[] bucket = null;
                var count = 0;

                foreach (var item in source)
                {
                    if (bucket == null)
                    {
                        bucket = new TSource[size];
                    }

                    bucket[count++] = item;

                    // The bucket is fully buffered before it's yielded
                    if (count != size)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Select is necessary so bucket contents are streamed too
                    yield return bucket.Select(x => x);

                    bucket = null;
                    count = 0;
                }

                // Return the last bucket with all remaining elements
                if (bucket != null && count > 0)
                {
                    yield return bucket.Take(count);
                }
            }
}
```

With this method, you can simply call `list.BreakIntoChunks(10)`;//To break into batch of 10 items